# MATLAB: Plotting a translated shape

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, transformation

I have a 7x2 matrix that contains data to plot out a shape. So my script is:

```
myMatrix = ([3,3;4,2;5,1;9,1;5,1;4,2;3,3]);
plot(myMatrix);
axis([-15 15 -15 15]);
```

I'm trying to translate it down 3 units and left 4 units. So that my shape will have the points `(0,0)` as the center. I could move it vertically simply by creating a new variable and defining it as `-3+myMatrix`. This will translate it down 3 units, but I am unable to move it along the x-axis.

There probably is a simple solution to this but I have been going to the documentation for matlab and googling but I couldn't find anything that will help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot(-3:3,myMatrix-3)
```

When no `x` is supplied to `plot`, the x coordinates are implicitly `1:length(y)` when `y` is a vector or `1:size(y,1)` for a matrix.  This instead supplies `-3:3` as `x`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot this works! Um can you explain a bit what the -3:3 represented? Sorry I'm still new to matlab

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  Type `-3:3` on the command line to see what that gives you, and see `help plot` for an explanation of the `plot(x,y)` syntax.  Please have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers